# How to assign/fill HTML select with JSON data in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm getting the json respose from perl script. This is the response looks like this.

```
alert (respose) // ouput - object
var json = JSON.stringify(response);
alert (json);

output:

{
    "brands": [
        {
            "brand_image_path": "/images/brands/aakash.png",
            "brand_name": "Aakash",
            "brand_id": "74"
        },
        {
            "brand_image_path": "/images/brands/aashirvaad.png",
            "brand_name": "Aashirvaad",
            "brand_id": "51"
        },
        {
            "brand_image_path": "/images/brands/yardley.png",
            "brand_name": "Yardley",
            "brand_id": "25"
        }
    ]
}
```

After getting the response from script I'm assigning it to $scope like this.

```
$scope.brandlist = response;
```

Both of these alert giving me the correct value.

```
alert ($scope.brandlist.brands[1].brand_name);
alert ($scope.brandlist.brands[2].brand_id);
```

How i want to fill a select list in my HTML page with this data. I'm using this code for same.

```
<select ID="select-add-new-product-brand-name" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="brand.brand_id as brand.brand_name for brand in brandlist"></select>
```

But it is not flling any data for me. What ia wrong in this??

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues here.

first off, you are looping through a single object ("brands") not the array of objects you want. when you get your ajax response object, set the brandlist to the array of objects in your controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('some/api/').then(function(result){
    $scope.brandList = result.brands;
  });
```

secondly, you should set the default select option in your controller. since you are trying to reference the brand_id via the brand_name property of your objects, you should set the default option like so:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('some/api/').then(function(result){
    $scope.brandList = result.brands;
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.brandList[1].brand_id; // set the second item as default
  });
```

now you should see everything in your rendered html.

see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/cgxhhe8Qh2UfCUAxSDio?p=preview